# iOS9, NSNotificationCenter, and when to release

Tags: ios, ios9

My code works on previous versions of iOS (6, 7, and 8) but on iOS 9 one of my variables is being released prior to when I explicitly release it. It looks like after the notification is processed NSNotificationCenter wants to release the object listening except that variable is still strong elsewhere.

There's a singleton class that holds all parameters for the application. It creates an object called CardParmsList.

```
static Parms * singleton = nil;

@implementation Parms

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        cardParms = [[ CardParmsList alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}


- (void)dealloc
{
    [cardParms release];

    [super dealloc];
}

-(void)getAllParms
{
    [[self getCardParms] getParms:"123456" length:16];
}
```

In the cardParms class when getting the parms it adds an observer for a notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(parseParms)
                                      name:CARD_PARMS_DONE
                                      object:nil];
```

Then in parseParms it removes the observer (no longer necessary in iOS9).

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:CARD_PARMS_DONE object:nil];
```

After parseParms is completed though I think the NSNotificationCenter is removing my instance of CardParmsList because release it being called. There is still a strong pointer to the object though so it shouldn't be cleaned up yet. Any thoughts?

```
0   0x00057f68 in -[CardParmsList release] at CardParms.mm:260
1   0x2655688e in -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] ()
2   0x264650a2 in _CFXNotificationPost ()
3   0x27247f0e in -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] ()
4   0x2724ca42 in -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] ()
```

Comment: clean up the question. You have problem with removing notification observer from `CardParmsList` which code you didn't show :(, you've shown some irrelevant code which only holds reference to interesting part. You didn't describe what is nature of your problem: is it a crash or is to strong reference cycle?

Comment: The ultimate issue is that once the observer is removed the object that was looking for the notification gets released and I don't think it should be. Once it's released when I go to access it later it blows up obviously. One other thing I didn't state clearly - the code works on iOS 6, 7, and 8, but on iOS 9 - no bueno.